# Time Series as a Django Model

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm pretty new to Django and its Rest Framework. I have that an api (third party) that output this pandas dataframe. I understand that I have to do a Many-to-One relationship for my models. The first model is just a list of all stocks and the second model should be the one holding the prices history (linked by a Foreign Key). How can I model the second table to store this data?

```
Date
2019-12-30    291.519989
2019-12-31    293.649994
2020-01-02    300.350006
2020-01-03    297.429993
2020-01-06    299.799988
2020-01-07    298.390015
2020-01-08    303.190002
2020-01-09    309.630005
2020-01-10    310.329987
```

Comment: i think three fields are enough, fk field to stock, time stamp and price

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please [consider marking the answer as acceptet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or add more information if you problem wasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first model is called `Stock`, the second one (let's call it `PriceHistory`) needs a ForeignKey-relation to it. For storing your data I'd take a [DateField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for your values given.

The resulting model would look like this:

```py
# models.py

class Stock(models.Model):
    ...


class PriceHistory(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(
        Stock,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='price_histories',
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=6,
        max_digits=9,
    )
```

If you only want one `price` per `date` per `stock`, you would need to add a [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)-constraint to `PriceHistory`, like: `unique_together = ['stock', 'date', 'price']`.